# splitting arrays in haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to do divide an array of strings into sub arrays. I am trying like the following;

```
content <- readFile "/tmp/foo.txt"
let all_paragraphs = lines content
let number = elemIndex "I THE LAY OF THE LAND" all_paragraphs
let number2 = elemIndex "IV THE MOST INTELLIGENT ANIMALS" all_paragraphs
```

Is it possible to parse the content to an array like;
let new_array = all_paragraphs[number,number2] or let new_Array = all_paragraphs(number:number2) a code similar to that?

Comment: While Haskell lists support all the same operations as arrays, referring to them as such is still not quite right. You can get the values at certain indices with `map (list !!) [ index1, index2 ]` or the values in that range with `drop index1.take index2 $ list`. Keep in mind that indexing a list is O(n), unlike O(1) for an array.

Comment: I am getting error says *** Term           : number2
*** Type           : Maybe Int
*** Does not match : Int

Comment: This error is completely unrelated to the question, and doesn't have any context. If you really like you may post another question regarding this error, but questions that show little to no research effort (like "i get this error - what do") are generally not well received.

Comment: You are right but the answer you gave me basically works for different types of data types rather that i posted in the question. This becomes the responsibility for you to solve that error :)

Comment: I think the problem is drop and take works with maybe int type but i am holding indexes as regular int. Can you give a more concrete and "for int type" solution if possible?

Comment: You've got it backwards - `take, drop :: Int -> [a] -> [a]` while `elemIndex :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Maybe Int`. If you want to get an `Int` from a `Maybe Int`, you can use a case statement or `maybe :: a -> (x -> a) -> Maybe x -> a`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99070/discussion-between-user2407038-and-user3104760).

Comment: @user3104760 No, it is no one else's responsibility but yours to solve your problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably talking about lists, not arrays, since there are no arrays in Haskell's Prelude and [lines](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:lines) returns `[String]`, i.e. a list of Strings.

So you want to get the sublist from index `n` to index `m` of a list? You can do that with a combination of [drop](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:drop) and [take](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:take).

However, this is not idiomatic functional programming where explicitly dealing with indices is discouraged, since it's error prone (e.g. off-by-one errors) and there are better ways. So it seems you want to get all the lines between the line `I THE LAY OF THE LAND` and the line `IV THE MOST INTELLIGENT ANIMALS`. You'd do that in idiomatic Haskell with:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  content <- readFile "/tmp/foo.txt"
  let ls = excerpt $ lines content
  -- the dollar just rearranges precedence, so this is the same as:
  -- ... = excerpt (lines content)
  print ls

-- do as little as possible in monads (the thing with `do ... let <- ...` etc)
-- rather define pure functions like this one and use them above...
excerpt :: [String] -> [String]
excerpt xs = takeWhile (/= "IV THE MOST INTELLIGENT ANIMALS")
  $ dropWhile (/= "I THE LAY OF THE LAND") xs

-- the excerpt function could alternatively also be written as
-- the composition of `takeWhile x` and `dropWhile y`
excerpt :: [String] -> [String]
excerpt = takeWhile (/= "IV THE MOST INTELLIGENT ANIMALS")
  . dropWhile (/= "I THE LAY OF THE LAND")
```

But you really should read up on how Haskell (and functional programming in general) take a different approach to solving problems than imperative languages. Maybe [Try Haskell](https://tryhaskell.org) is more to your liking, and if you wonder what a function does (or are looking for one), [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) is indispensable.

Comment: Can i do that in one line and with using just one list?

Comment: let new_array = takeWhile (/= "IV THE MOST INTELLIGENT ANIMALS") 
  $ dropWhile (/= "I THE LAY OF THE LAND") all_paragraphs
print new_array

Gives an error with that code. What can be the problem?

Comment: Haskell takes a slightly different mindset than more traditional programming languages ;) (stop calling lists arrays, they're really not the same thing!) I'd recommend playing around with `ghci` first, before messing with IO, `puts` and `print`. A good place to start is http://learnyouahaskell.com

Comment: Sorry about that. I am looking for a shortcut way for the problem :)

Comment: Do you want a quick solution or learn to program Haskell? :P I don't see the point in you having a program that works, if you don't understand why it works.

Comment: @user3104760 What does "Gives an error with that code" mean? What code?

Comment: I want it to work the way i want it to and i want to make it in a single line in which i can declare the upper and lower bound. What do you mean by without understanding?

Comment: @CRDrost that error is gone it was a simple syntax error my mistake :)

Comment: @user3104760 I meant that it doesn't help you much if I give you the correct code but you don't understand why it works. I expanded the answer a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Like @mb21 indicates but does not state outright, what you are looking for is a simple sequence of `drop` and `take`.

For example, defining in your program

```hs
slice list lo hi = drop lo (take hi list)
```

will let you do slices of the form that you're used to in JavaScript and Python, and you could also define it with an infix operator and a pair, if you wanted. Let's say we want to use `.!` for a slice operator, and handle negative arguments like in JS and Python; we then define at the top level:

```hs
list .! (lo, hi) = drop l $ take h list
  where
    len = length list
    handle_negative x | x < 0 = x + len | otherwise = x
    h = handle_negative hi
    l = handle_negative lo
```

This should work on any finite list; negative indices will in general screw up potentially infinite lists: though this problem is removable for the second index it is essential for the first one. So for example to do the slice `[0..] .! (1, -2)` which should be equivalent to `[1..]` you would in general need to keep `list` and `drop (-last_index) list` which you travel down together, emitting elements of the first while the second is not `[]`.